# Drawing tranformer in circuitTikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm currently getting started with circuiTikz and have a little of trouble drawing transformers. I don't really get how to place the nodes correctly?
Here's what I'm trying to draw:

[image: Circuit]

And the code I have so far (the main difference is that I am replacing the Rg, Re and Le by a generic impedance Ze):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
    (0,0)   to[V,v=$U_{in}$]    
    (0,2) to[generic,l=$Z_{e}$]
    (2,2) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A1) node[anchor=east] {}
    (T.A2) node[anchor=east] {}
    (T.B1) node[anchor=west] {}
    (T.B2) node[anchor=west] {}
    (T.base) node{1:S$_{d}$}
    (4,2)   to[R=$R_{ms}$] 
    (6,2) to[C=$C_{ms}$] 
    (8,2) to[L=$M_{ms}$] 
    (10,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

This code gives me this pretty messy diagram:

[image: My messy result]

I think I didn't quite got the placement and node things correctly so if anyone could help me understand this it would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note [transformer core] (p 29), and [mirror] and [invert] (p 43).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (2,2) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A2)  -- + (-2,0) coordinate (aux1)
            to[V^=$U_{in}$]    (aux1  |- T.A1) 
            to[generic,l=$Z_{e}$] (T.A1)           
    (T.B1)  to[R=$R_{ms}$] + (2,0)
            to[C=$C_{ms}$] + (2,0)
            to[L=$M_{ms}$] + (2,0) |- (T.B2);
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

in above mwe are first positioned transformer. then are relative to it placed other circuit elements.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko, that looks really nice! How can I get the voltage generator to point upwards?

Comment: @Choups, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't understand what's the "(T.A2)  -- + (-2,0) coordinate (aux1)" is doing exactly, could you detail a bit more?

Comment: @Choups: Please have a look at the circuitikz manual.

Comment: @Choups, `(T.A2) -- + (-2,0) coordinate (aux1)` draw line from transformer terminal `T.A2` for 2cm to the left direction and on its end determine new coordinate named `aux1` for latter use in drawing. `-- + (...)` means that you draw line in direction and amount determined with `...`.

Comment: @genodeftest I did, and they're pretty evasive about the whole placement and line drawing. Instead of grinding my teeth on the examples that I do not understand fully and couldn't reproduce if asked to, I though it might be faster and easier to ask for some advice here. Zarko, thanks a lot for the clarifications, I'm starting to get the logic. I'll just mess around and try to draw some circuit to get the hang of it!

Comment: @Choups, `circuitikz` is based on `tikz, so all rules, syntax, elements ... from `tikz` works also in `circuitikz`.

Comment: @Zarko thanks, I've never used    tikz before so I'll give the manual a look

Comment: @Choups, now you can consider to vote and accepting answer (by clicking on up-pen and check mark at top left side of answer) :-)